# Line Type in r fixed only to six values in plot function

Tags: r

in r the line type is fixed only to six values (1-6) when I am trying to use it in a plot function.

[image]

I searched for a while on the internet, but all solutions are tightly coupled with ggplot. Those solutions are useless for my case, I want to tweak the line type in the plot function.

Is there any possibility to increase the number of values of the line type, for example (1-10), which in turns gives me ten possibilities instead of six possibilities to draw different lines.

Here my code,

```
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("1.0", "1", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.9", "2", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.8", "3", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.7", "4", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.6", "5", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.5", "6", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.4", "7", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.3", "8", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.2", "9", E(g)$Weight)
E(g)$Weight <-gsub("0.1", "10", E(g)$Weight)
l_line<-E(g)$Weight
l_line
l_line<-strtoi(l_line, base = 0L)
l_line

plot(g,layout=l2,
 vertex.size = 1.5,
 edge.lty= l_line,
 rescale=F,axes=TRUE,ylim=c(0,0.7),xlim=c(0,1), asp = 0,
 vertex.label.cex= 0.5,
 edge.arrow.width = 0.0,
 vertex.label = LETTERS[1:10],
 edge.arrow.size = 0.0,
 edge.color ="black")
```

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need to add a reproducible example (some data, your code etc.). Maybe using line widths or some shapes along them would work?

Comment: I added the code, but now the funny thing, that my question marked as a duplicate for one answer, which is exclusive for ggplot. I couldn't integrate it to plot function.

Comment: See here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/#standard-graphics

Comment: Also, yes, it is not a duplicate, but I still cannot understand why someone would choose base R over ggplot for plotting ;)